# IIB - How to pass UserContext in a SOAPAsyncRequest node

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, soap, messagebroker

I'm trying to pass the user context from a SOAPAsyncRequest node to a SOAPAsyncResponse node by overriding the local environment like described in the IBM documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56202_.htm#ac56202_leo) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56210_.htm).

Here is a part of my flow:
[image: flow]

In *Map to N* compute node (Compute Mode is set on *LocalEnvironment and Message*):

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment = InputLocalEnvironment;
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.RequestId = InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestIdentifier;
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.Language = InputRoot.HTTPInputHeader."Accept-Language";
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Request.UserContext = CAST(ASBITSTREAM(OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables) as BLOB);
```

In *SetRequestId* compute node:

```
DECLARE UserContext BLOB;
SET UserContext = InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Response.UserContext;
```

Debug value of the LocalEnvironment after the Map to N node:

```
LocalEnvironment
    Destination
        HTTP
            RequestIdentifier:BLOB:[B@54d21920
        RouterList
            DestinationData
                labelName:CHARACTER:GET
        SOAP
            Request
                UserContext:BLOB:[B@3d098be1
```

Debug value after the *SOAP Async Response N* node:

```
LocalEnvironment
    SOAP
        Response
            MessageCorrelId:BLOB:[B@a075817
    Destination
        RouterList
            DestinationData
                labelName:CHARACTER:findXYZ
```

Though the LocalEnvironment is correctly set after the *Map to N node* (see debug above), the value of `UserContext` is always null.

**edit:** Except for the UserContext problem, my flow is working properly. To answer the first comment, yes, the unique identifiers are correctly set.

Comment: Are your request and response nodes paired by the Unique identifier property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't succeed to pass the *Variables* tree structure but I found a workaround by concatenating the values and storing it into a BLOB. Neither it is the cleanest way to resolve it, nor is this solution easy to implement when dealing with more than two objects.

In *Map To D* Compute Node:

```
SET ConcatenatedContext = 'YourFirstString' || ';' || 'YourSecondString';
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Request.UserContext = CAST(ConcatenatedContext AS BLOB CCSID 1208);
```

In *SetRequestId* Compute Node:

```
DECLARE RawValue CHARACTER;
SET RawValue = CAST(InputLocalEnvironment.SOAP.Response.UserContext AS CHARACTER CCSID 1208);
SET FirstString = SUBSTRING(RawValue BEFORE ';');
SET SecondString = SUBSTRING(RawValue AFTER ';');
```